# I am not able to decide the programming language for selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

i am learning selenium concepts.while in the process i am not able to decide to go for which programming language.

1- JAVA or 2- PHP

i have worked on PHP and have gud knowledge about it.so please tell me which is the good one php or JAVA and why???

Answer (score 3):

Well the decission is not only yours. In my own example, I have chosen Java programming language.

Not because I have experience with it.

Not because I might have feeling, that "java is better than PHP"

Simply because *all* developers in my company work in Java. And because I need help with programming, it is *almost always* better idea to first ask around in the office than to post your question here on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I use groovy(he simply of java), and i use Geb freamwork for this.
You can read about this tool there: [link](http://www.gebish.org/)

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well decision is your own. In selenium choose programing language in which you have sufficient knowledge and you have a grip on the language.

Both programing language is good and both have its own scope in the market